# How to determine how much "slack" in postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

I've got a postgres database which I recently vacuumed.  I understand that process marks space as available for future use, but for the most part does not return it to the OS.

I need to track how close I am to using up that available "slack space" so I can ensure the entire database does not start to grow again.

Is there a way to see how much empty space the database has inside it?

I'd prefer to just do a VACUUM FULL and monitor disk consumption, but I can't lock the table for a prolonged period, nor do I have the disk space.

Running version 13 on headless Ubuntu if that's important.

Comment: It’s not that simple. Depending on which page new rows are inserted into, more space may be allocated even if there is free space available, for example a large row that won’t fit in any single page’s free space. Just vacuum frequently and provide enough disk free space for the DB to grow. Or warehouse/delete old rows if they are not needed in the main table.

Comment: What is it you are really wanting to find out, the amount of bloat in the database or the space it is occupying on disk? Unless this going to be a read only database or deletes will equal inserts the database is going to grow in one form or another. So you need to be more specific about what growth concerns you.

Comment: For the most part, the db is insert and read only; when the overall size gets too large, I copy records to a warehouse, delete them from the database, then vacuum.  I am highly constrained on disk space, so I don't want the db getting any bigger than it is, but the warehousing process is painful, so don't want to do it more frequently than necessary. I'd like to be able to know when the database was about to start growing, then warehouse the data.  Records are roughly uniform in size, so I might be able to use record count as a proxy for "fullness", but was looking for a more direct measure.

Answer (score 0):

Just like internal free space is not given back to the OS, it also isn't shared between tables or other relations (like indexes).  So having freespace in one table isn't going to help if a different table is the one growing.  You can use [pg_freespacemap](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgfreespacemap.html) to get a fast approximate answer for each table, or [pgstattuple](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstattuple.html) for more detailed data.